# Filling records, sending a row as a PDF, sending the pdf to specific email addresses and storing the PDF in another table as an attachment

Tags: pdf, automation, airtable

I have a workflow that I need to get done in Airtable:

1. The user fills a row in a table.
2. The row that gets filled is made into a pdf using page designer.
3. The designed page is sent as a pdf to some static email addresses.
4. The pdf also needs to be stored in another table as an attachment.

I did the first two parts. I’m having trouble doing the other two as I cannot figure out anything to do about it. I would be grateful if anyone helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create the last two steps of your scenario using "automations."

- when the PDF is saved into airtable, use the automation tool to send that attachment to the email provided using an IF statement.
- You can then create a THEN statement for the automation to complete after each email has been sent.

You'll need a pro account if you want to send more than 100 emails per day I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that specialized software is better suited for your tasks, which allows you to generate PDF files from a row, send them to recipients, and save them in another table as an attachment.

I use Plumsail Documents for such purposes. This software allows you to generate documents with data from any system, sign them, send them by email and save them across any app. This software has many integrations, including Airtable. The good thing is that they have a free trial period of 30 days, with no credit card required. I recommend reading an article about [comparing Airtable Page Designer and Plumsail Documents](https://plumsail.com/blog/airtable-page-designer-alternative/).

In short, you will need to follow a few steps:

1. Create a document template in Plumsail Documents processes to
   generate documents with data from Airtable from this template;
2. Configure the delivery and storage parameters of the finished
   document;
3. Connect Airtable to Plumsail Documents using Zapier or Power
   Automate and configure data transport from Airtable to document
   template;